# Is it possible to pass additional arguments or form instances to django formset?

Tags: django, django-forms

My models.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
   company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class TimePeriod(models.Model):
   period = models.CharField(max_length=4)

class Unit(models.Model):
   unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   unit_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class DataElement(models.Model):
   data_element_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Source(models.Model):
   source_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)    

class CompanyData(models.Model):
   company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
   time_period = models.ForeignKey(TimePeriod)
   data_element = models.ForeignKey(DataElement)
   unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit) 
   source = models.ForeignKey(Source)
   value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
```

I'd like to have form similar to:

--company--, --time period--

- data element1: --value--, --unit--, --source--
- data element2: --value--, --unit--, --source--
- ...
- data elementN: --value--, --unit--, --source--

My forms.py now:

```
class CompanyTimeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyData
        fields = ('company', 'time_period')

class CompanyDataForm(ModelForm):
#    data_element = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput()) 
#    def __init__(self, extra):
#        ... init data_element ...
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyData
        fields = ('value', 'unit', 'source')
```

and usage:

```
top_form = CompanyChainTimeForm(request.POST or None)
CompanyDataFormSet = formset_factory(CompanyDataForm, extra=X)
formset = CompanyDataFormSet()
```

Is it possible to initialize empty formset, then fetch DataElement.objects.all() and make something similar to
formset.add(CompanyDataForm(...DataElement.pk...))

Or what would be the best option for my case?

Answer (score 0):

If time_period was a field on the `Company` then, clearly it would be straight forward.

In the appearance of your form, you want to make it appear as such, even though it isn't.

The best thing would be to ditch the `ModelForm`, use a `Form` with a `save` and a `formset_factory` to generate many forms for that. Within your own `save`, of course you can create an instance of the `TimePeriod` and associate with the `Company` before you actually save it.

Comment: The problem isn't TimePeriod rather CompamyData.data_element. I have a common fields for every new records (CompanyTimeForm) and many (N=number of DataElements records) similar forms, that will be saved as N CompanyData records (each will have the same fields from CompanyTimeForm). But each from this similar forms should have unique hidden dataelement.pk, that I could pass to CompanyDataForm (commented strings), but actually I can't (at least don't know how).

Answer (score 0):

It seems as it's impossible to use formset here.
I've done it via forms set with prefixes:

```
...
data_forms = []
is_valid = True
for de in DataElement.objects.all():
    data_form = CompanyDataForm(request.POST or None, initial={'data_element': de.pk}, value_label=de, prefix="de-%s" % de.pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not data_form.is_valid():
            is_valid = False
    data_forms.append(data_form)
```